# Is there a way i can customize an Electro theme WordPress site masthead?

Tags: wordpress

[image: Masthead image]

I need help in achieving the following:
Move the shoping cart infront of the search button.
fiting the menu items in the page, several are disapearing to the right

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. I'm unfamiliar with the theme but guessing it uses WooCommerce?

It sounds like you may want to create a Child Theme on this new theme and edit it that way - if you're adamant on using it.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

WooCommerce offers lots of documentation on how to edit their themes by creating your own template files which overwrites the default ones they use.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-theme-developer-handbook/

Comment: The theme is electro as indicated above